# Nilpotent linear map property

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ be a vectorial space and $f:V \to V$ a linear map that is nilpotent (that is, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ that $f^N=0$, the null map). Show that if $dim(V)=n$, then $f^n=0$.

My thoughts are:

If $f$ is nilpotent, certainly it's not injective or surjective. So we have $V \supsetneq f(V) \supsetneq f(f(V)) \cdots$. So doing that process $n$ times, we would have $f^n(V)=\{0\}$. Is that right?

Comment: maybe you can say something about $\dim(f(V))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost. The reason is wrong, as a map that is neither injective nor surjective can as well map a lower dimensional subspace to one of equal dimension. (Example: Any projection like $(x,y)\mapsto (x,0)$ will map a whole subspace to itself.)

But consider: If for one $k$ we have $f^k(V) = f^{k+1}(V)$ then $f^k(V)$ is fixed under $f$. Thus $f^l(V) = f^k(V)$ for all $l\geq k$. This implies that if $f$ is nilpotent then this property can only be if $f^k(V)=\{0\}$.

So either your reasoning works or we have that already $f^k(V)=\{0\}$ for some $k<n$.

Answer (score 1):

If you know about minimal polynomials then here is a simple solution: $f$ is a root of the polynomial $x^N$ for some $N$. This means the minimal polynomial of $f$ has to divide $x^N$, and so it has the form $x^t$ for some $t\geq 0$. But the degree of the minimal polynomial is at most the dimension of $V$, and so $t\leq n$.

Comment: But for that you’d need something like minimal polynomials for non-commutative rings.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If we work over the field $F$, then $F[x]$ is a commutative ring. The minimal polynomial of $f$ is the monic polynomial which generates the (principal) ideal $\{p\in F[x]: p(f)=0\}$.

Comment: But the ring of linear maps of some vector space into itself is not a field, it is not even commutative.

Comment: Why does it matter? You can put a matrix/linear map into a polynomial in $F[x]$ . You can read about minimal polynomials in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)

Comment: What is even $F$ in your case? I mean, where do you get this from?

Comment: $V$ is a vector space over some field $F$, right? For a polynomial $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i\in F[x]$ we can define the linear map $p(f)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_if^i$. The polynomials which satisfy $p(f)=0$ form an ideal of $F[x]$, and the monic polynomial which generates it is called the minimal polynomial of $f$ over the field $F$.

Comment: Ah, I understand, yes, that seems logical.

Comment: But using your prove I think you can even deduct that if $t$ is minimal so that $f^t=0$ then $f^0,\ldots,f^{t-1}$ are linar independent. This is nice!

Comment: Yes, this is true, because $f$ can't be a root of a nonzero polynomial in $F[x]$ with degree less than the degree of the minimal polynomial.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I mean. It just seems to me that this is an increadibly cheap proof to that property.